# Compact Metric Space and Weak Contraction

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f: X \rightarrow X$ is a weak contraction, then is $f$ also a generalized contraction?

That is, if for $f$ we have that, $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, then do we have for $f$ that for any $0<\alpha<\beta<\infty$, there exists some constant $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq \lambda d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ with $\alpha \leq d(x,y) \leq \beta$.

Comment: @Ian I think it's true for either $f$ continuous or $f$ discontinuous. I'm just not sure how to prove this. I think that if $f$ is a weak contraction and $X$ is a compact metric space then $f$ has a unique fixed point in $X$. I think that this couldn't be the case unless $f$ was also a generalized contraction by Banach fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$\{(x,y): d(x,y) \geq \alpha\}$ is a closed, hence compact subset of $X \times X$ and the function $g(x,y)=\frac {d(f(x),f(y))} {d(x,y)}$ is continuous on it. Hence it attains its supremum at some point and the hypothesis tells us that the value a this point must be less than $1$. Call this supremum $\lambda$ and you are done.

Note: We can use the metric $D((x,y),(x',y'))=d(x,x')+d(y,y')$ on $X \times X$.

Comment: Is it to sufficient to show that if $f$ has a fixed point when $f$ is a weak contraction on a compact metric space, then by the Banach fixed point theorem, we know that $f$ must also be a generalized contraction?

Comment: You seem to use the converse of Banach Fixed Point Theorem which is not true.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I see your point. But if we call said fixed point $\lambda$, then do we not have our desired inequality for a generalized contraction?

Comment: Fixed point is  a point of $X$. $\lambda$ is a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Agh, thank you. 
I'm trying to prove that this is true via contradiction, not direct proof. So if I suppose that $f$ is a weak contraction on a compact space, but $f$ is not a generalized contraction, I need to arrive at some contradiction. I thought that showing $f$ has a fixed point might help me arrive at a contradiction.